# Fuses blown and PC backup power ... and a mystéry

Tags: fuses, ups

I must admit it, what happened goes beyond my logic, so I need help to understand.
My two computers and the peripheral devices are powered through an UPS (backup power). I use 3 power strips to power all these guys.

This morning I noticed that the loudspeakers of my PC where down. After a few tests, conclusion : the transformer is dead.
So I turned on my two bigger loudspeakers (KRK Rokit 5), ... well I couldn't ...  After a few tests, conclusion : the fuses are blown.
I changed both fuses with the spare fuses, the loudspeaker turned on 10 seconds and then ... blown fuses again. I thought that there was a problem with the loudspeakers.

I found new pc loudspeakers. I plugged their transformer in one of the power strips. It worked, 3 minutes, but the volume was low and an ugly overdrive occurred in my music. Then the transformer blew up too.

I started thinking that these events were connected (I am a fast thinker) ...

I measured the tension : 237 volts (after UPS and before and in several other plugs in the house ... which is normal in France (where I live) The state electricity company told me that tension ins considered normal up to 250 volts.

All the other devices inducing computer work perfectly. ... but I wonder if it is really reasonable to use them.

Anyway I have no explanation (UPS ? power strips ? ) ... and i need to do my work. I know that life would be worse if the Great Plague was back but i will be grateful to any person able to give me a clue.

Thanks, 
Nicolas,
France

Comment: I think you should call an exorcist or the ghostbusters.

Comment: Right, but they are retired I heard ... (I am not, so i need to solve this ...) :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a common mode voltage problem between your audio source and your speakers.

Start looking for a fault from the audio source that is feeding the speakers. Measure the voltage from the audio out connectors (each pin) to the ground on your outlet strips. You should not find anything over a volt or two.

Also measure the voltage from one ground pin to another on the outlet strips. You should see close to zero volts. Do the same with the two round pins between the power strips to make certain that one strip isn't cross wired.

Comment: Thanks Glenn ! I neglected these ground pins ! that could explain everything.